# error:SyntaxError: Unexpected token g in JSON at position 0

Tags: java, angular, eclipse, angular8, http-error

This error gives me when I enter letters, if I enter numbers it does not give me. I would like to know how to fix it.

Angular code
auth.service.ts

```
 refactor(data: string): Observable<any>{
        return this.http.post<any>(apiUrl, data)
          .pipe(
            tap(_ => this.log('refactor')),
            catchError(this.handleError('refactor', []))
          );
      }
```

component.ts

```
this.anomtextService.refactor($('#file').val().toString())
         .subscribe(res => {

           $('#textAnom').val(res);

         }, (err) => {
           console.log(err);
           alert(err.error);
         });

     }
```

API REST JAVA

```
@PostMapping(path = "/rename")
    public String getPathByDoc(@RequestBody String text) {

        return text;

    }
```

[image]

token.interceptor.ts

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
    HttpRequest,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpEvent,
    HttpInterceptor,
    HttpResponse,
    HttpErrorResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private router: Router) {}
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

      const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
      if (token) {
        request = request.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
          }
        });
      }
      if (!request.headers.has('Content-Type')) {
        request = request.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
          }
        });
      }
      request = request.clone({
        headers: request.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json')
      });
      return next.handle(request).pipe(
        map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
          if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            console.log('event--->>>', event);
          }
          return event;
        }),
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          console.log(error);
          if (error.status === 401) {
            this.router.navigate(['login']);
          }
          if (error.status === 400) {
            alert(error.error);
          }
          return throwError(error);
        }));
  }
}
```

Maybe the fault is there, I've been pooping things all day.

I would appreciate the help you can give me.

Possible solution they have given me:
Angulars HttpClient expects your response type to be json and tries to parse it. You can tell the HttpClient to accept plain text instead.

But I don't know how to solve it

Comment: 1) Your Angular code is making a request. 2) It explicitly says that it's expecting the server to respond with JSON: `'application/json'`.  3) The server response is `"ghi"`.  4) "ghi" is *NOT* valid JSON, hence the error.  5) SOLUTION: Fix the server (to return JSON), and/or fix Angular (to accept non-JSON text).

Comment: This works thanks to everyone, a pleasure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angulars `HttpClient` expects your response type to be json and tries to parse it.
You can tell the `HttpClient` to accept plain text instead.

```
refactor(data: string): Observable<any>{
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=utf-8');

    return this.http.post(apiUrl, data,{headers,responseType: 'text'})
          .pipe(
            tap(_ => this.log('refactor')),
            catchError(this.handleError('refactor', []))
          );
}
```

Comment: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 15, '(url: string, body: any, options: { headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe: "events"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }): Observable<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '"text"' is not assignable to type '"json"'.

Comment: I have a token.interceptor, do I still have to put it there? I update the question and upload the token.interceptor code

Comment: I updated the answer with a header, I just saw that you are also sending plain text and no json. Does this help?

Comment: If this still does not work try responseType: 'text' as 'text'. There is an issue here:https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18586#issuecomment-527486578

Comment: @Max K: You're absolutely correct about the problem: Angular is expecting JSON, and the server is returning plain text.  Your response is good.  But perhaps the server  (the "REST API") *should* be returning JSON, not text.  The OP can look [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-restful/spring-rest-hello-world-json-example/) or [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-json)